# JQuery AJAX retrieving an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to use json_encode so that my jquery ajax function can retrieve data from my php script however the array I am attempting to encode and retrieve is an array of objects

```
$la_uselessinfo = array();
$lv_cnt = 0;

$uselessinfo = pg_execute($gv_dbconn, "uselessinfo_cur", array());
while($la_row = pg_fetch_row($uselessinfo)) {

    $la_uselessinfo[$lv_cnt]["uinf_idno"] = $la_row[0];
    $la_uselessinfo[$lv_cnt]["uinf_desc"] = $la_row[1];
    $lv_cnt = $lv_cnt + 1;

}

echo json_encode($la_uselessinfo);
```

I am trying to retrieve this using the jquery ajax function

```
$.ajax({
    url     : 'scripts/phpfunctions.php',
    type    : 'GET',
    data    : {'action':'sel_uselessinfo'},
    success : function(data) {
                  //console.log(data);
                  console.log(data["uinf_desc"][0]);
              },
    error   : function(log) {
                  console.log(log.message);
              }
});
```

I am getting the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I can't tell if it's going wrong in the php code or the jquery code, what is the correct way to retrieve an array of objects?

Comment: You have one more parameter to `parse`. you are sending it as `[$lv_cnt]["uinf_idno"]` right?

Comment: You need to parse the response like `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: Where you do `json_encode(array($la_uselessinfo));` are you sure you dont really want `json_encode($la_uselessinfo);`?   `$la_uselessinfo` is already an array, no need to wrap it again, and doing so causes you to misjudge the depth of your array

Comment: Good idea @Delighted

Comment: Still have the issue?

Comment: What is `console.log(data)`? Looks like what you are outputting does not match what you are trying to read.

Comment: I used your change @ DelightedD0D and the JSON.parse as suggested by @RayonDabre so I am getting a JSON object now "[{"uinf_idno":"1","uinf_desc":"website db                    "},{"uinf_idno":"2","uinf_desc":"local apache                  "}]". Is it possible to loop through this result?

Comment: you dont need `JSON.parse` jQuery will do that automatically, yes you can loop over the result, just a sec for an example

Comment: Oh wow it works without JSON.parse that's amazing, thanks @DelightedD0D

Comment: YW, @void has you covered for your original question, I left an answer below just so I could explain the whole issue and show you how to loop over the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your PHP to:

```
$la_uselessinfo = array();
$lv_cnt = 0;

$uselessinfo = pg_execute($gv_dbconn, "uselessinfo_cur", array());
while($la_row = pg_fetch_row($uselessinfo)) {

    $la_uselessinfo[$lv_cnt]["uinf_idno"] = $la_row[0];
    $la_uselessinfo[$lv_cnt]["uinf_desc"] = $la_row[1];
    $lv_cnt = $lv_cnt + 1;

}

echo json_encode($la_uselessinfo); //$la_uselessinfo is already an array, no need to wrap it again, and doing so causes you to misjudge the depth of your array
```

Then change your jQuery to :

```
$.ajax({
    url     : 'scripts/phpfunctions.php',
    type    : 'GET',
    data    : {'action':'sel_uselessinfo'},
    success : function(data) {
                  //console.log(data);
                  console.log(data[0]["uinf_desc"]); // this line changed
              },
    error   : function(log) {
                  console.log(log.message);
              }
});
```

To loop over your results do this:

```js
 // sample data
var data = [{
  "uinf_idno": "1",
  "uinf_desc": "website db "
}, {
  "uinf_idno": "2",
  "uinf_desc": "local apache "
}]



$.each(data,function(i,e){
       var uinf_idno = e.uinf_idno;
       var uinf_desc = e.uinf_desc;
       
      $('#result').append('uinf_idno= '+uinf_idno+' and uinf_desc= '+uinf_desc+' <br>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: this is perfect and very indepth

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url     : 'scripts/phpfunctions.php',
    type    : 'GET',
    data    : {'action':'sel_uselessinfo'},
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(data) {
                  console.log(data[0]["uinf_desc"]);
                  console.log(data[0]["uinf_desc"]);
              },
```

It should be `data[0]["uinf_desc"]` as written in your PHP

Comment: I wasnt the downvoter, but maybe because this will work now with the OP's edit,but before they edited though, this would have needed to be `data[0][0]["uinf_desc"]`

Comment: It will be just `data[0]["uinf_desc"]`

Comment: Now yes, but orriginally the OP's code was calling `json_encode(array($la_uselessinfo));` wich was wrapping the array in **another** arry before turning it into `JSON` meaning it would need to be accessed via `data[0][0]["uinf_desc"]`